Improve performance of query with inner join, operation between tables, and array_agg
I am using DuckDB, which should follows postgresql's syntax for the most part.

I have two tables t_cons (~200k) and t_flows (~1.2M).
For a row of t_cons there are many t_flows that match asset, year, rep_period
Of those, I want those for which an operation returns > 0. The operation uses other columns from both tables.
I want to aggregate all of these per row of t_cons, storing all t_flows.variable_index that satisfy operation > 0.

I managed to get the result with two queries, one for an INNER JOIN computing the operation and filtering and the second to aggregate, but it is too slow.
I am trying to join them in a single query and remove the inner join to prevent the scan, but I'm not that proficient with SQL. Any help is much appreciated.

The link for the sql and a sample of the data:
https://gist.github.com/abelsiqueira/d8124d6b32db8e20297be4440405e093
CREATE
OR REPLACE TABLE t_flows AS
SELECT
    *
FROM
    't_flows.csv';

CREATE
OR REPLACE TABLE t_cons AS
SELECT
    *
FROM
    't_cons.csv';

CREATE
OR REPLACE TABLE t_incoming_nonzero AS
SELECT
    t_flows.from_asset,
    t_flows.to_asset,
    t_flows.year,
    t_flows.rep_period,
    t_flows.variable_index,
    t_cons.time_block_start,
    greatest(
        0,
        1 + least(t_flows.time_block_end, t_cons.time_block_end) - greatest(t_flows.time_block_start, t_cons.time_block_start)
    ) AS duration
FROM
    t_flows
    INNER JOIN t_cons ON t_flows.to_asset = t_cons.asset
    AND t_flows.year = t_cons.year
    AND t_flows.rep_period = t_cons.rep_period
WHERE
    duration > 0;

CREATE
OR REPLACE TABLE t_result AS
SELECT
    t_cons.asset,
    t_cons.year,
    t_cons.rep_period,
    t_cons.time_block_start,
    COALESCE(indices, []) AS indices,
    COALESCE(durations, []) AS durations,
FROM
    t_cons
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT
            to_asset AS asset,
            YEAR,
            rep_period,
            time_block_start,
            array_agg(variable_index) AS indices,
            array_agg(duration) AS durations,
        FROM
            t_incoming_nonzero
        GROUP BY
            to_asset,
            YEAR,
            rep_period,
            time_block_start
    ) AS t_tmp ON t_cons.asset = t_tmp.asset
    AND t_cons.year = t_tmp.year
    AND t_cons.rep_period = t_tmp.rep_period
    AND t_cons.time_block_start = t_tmp.time_block_start;

SELECT
    *
FROM
    t_result;


Output of "EXPLAIN ANALYZE" (DuckDB doesn't support the other settings for explain):
┌─────────────────────────────────────┐
│┌───────────────────────────────────┐│
││    Query Profiling Information    ││
│└───────────────────────────────────┘│
└─────────────────────────────────────┘
EXPLAIN (     ANALYZE ) CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE t_incoming_nonzero AS SELECT     t_flows.from_asset,     t_flows.to_asset,     t_flows.year,     t_flows.rep_period,     t_flows.variable_index,     t_cons.time_block_start,     greatest(         0,         1 + least(t_flows.time_block_end, t_cons.time_block_end) - greatest(t_flows.time_block_start, t_cons.time_block_start)     ) AS duration FROM     t_flows     INNER JOIN t_cons ON t_flows.to_asset = t_cons.asset     AND t_flows.year = t_cons.year     AND t_flows.rep_period = t_cons.rep_period WHERE     duration > 0;
┌────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│┌──────────────────────────────────────────────┐│
││              Total Time: 20.11s              ││
│└──────────────────────────────────────────────┘│
└────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
┌───────────────────────────┐
│           QUERY           │
└─────────────┬─────────────┘
┌─────────────┴─────────────┐
│      EXPLAIN_ANALYZE      │
│    ────────────────────   │
│           0 Rows          │
│          (0.00s)          │
└─────────────┬─────────────┘
┌─────────────┴─────────────┐
│      CREATE_TABLE_AS      │
│    ────────────────────   │
│           1 Rows          │
│          (0.13s)          │
└─────────────┬─────────────┘
┌─────────────┴─────────────┐
│         PROJECTION        │
│    ────────────────────   │
│         from_asset        │
│          to_asset         │
│            year           │
│         rep_period        │
│       variable_index      │
│      time_block_start     │
│          duration         │
│                           │
│        1372400 Rows       │
│          (0.02s)          │
└─────────────┬─────────────┘
┌─────────────┴─────────────┐
│         PROJECTION        │
│    ────────────────────   │
│             #0            │
│             #1            │
│             #2            │
│             #3            │
│             #4            │
│             #5            │
│             #6            │
│            #10            │
│            #11            │
│                           │
│        1372400 Rows       │
│          (0.00s)          │
└─────────────┬─────────────┘
┌─────────────┴─────────────┐
│           FILTER          │
│    ────────────────────   │
│  (greatest(0, ((1 + least │
│      (time_block_end,     │
│     time_block_end)) -    │
│  greatest(time_block_start│
│ , time_block_start))) > 0)│
│                           │
│        1372400 Rows       │
│          (78.74s)         │
└─────────────┬─────────────┘
┌─────────────┴─────────────┐
│         HASH_JOIN         │
│    ────────────────────   │
│      Join Type: INNER     │
│                           │
│        Conditions:        │
│  rep_period = rep_period  ├──────────────┐
│        year = year        │              │
│      to_asset = asset     │              │
│                           │              │
│      5184051200 Rows      │              │
│          (49.01s)         │              │
└─────────────┬─────────────┘              │
┌─────────────┴─────────────┐┌─────────────┴─────────────┐
│         TABLE_SCAN        ││         TABLE_SCAN        │
│    ────────────────────   ││    ────────────────────   │
│          t_flows          ││           t_cons          │
│                           ││                           │
│        Projections:       ││        Projections:       │
│          to_asset         ││           asset           │
│            year           ││            year           │
│         rep_period        ││         rep_period        │
│       time_block_end      ││       time_block_end      │
│      time_block_start     ││      time_block_start     │
│         from_asset        ││                           │
│       variable_index      ││                           │
│                           ││                           │
│        1335900 Rows       ││        220460 Rows        │
│          (0.04s)          ││          (0.00s)          │
└───────────────────────────┘└───────────────────────────┘
┌─────────────────────────────────────┐
│┌───────────────────────────────────┐│
││    Query Profiling Information    ││
│└───────────────────────────────────┘│
└─────────────────────────────────────┘
EXPLAIN (     ANALYZE ) CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE t_result AS SELECT     t_cons.asset,     t_cons.year,     t_cons.rep_period,     t_cons.time_block_start,     COALESCE(indices, []) AS indices,     COALESCE(durations, []) AS durations, FROM     t_cons     LEFT JOIN (         SELECT             to_asset AS asset,             YEAR,             rep_period,             time_block_start,             array_agg(variable_index) AS indices,             array_agg(duration) AS durations,         FROM             t_incoming_nonzero         GROUP BY             to_asset,             YEAR,             rep_period,             time_block_start     ) AS t_tmp ON t_cons.asset = t_tmp.asset     AND t_cons.year = t_tmp.year     AND t_cons.rep_period = t_tmp.rep_period     AND t_cons.time_block_start = t_tmp.time_block_start;
┌────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│┌──────────────────────────────────────────────┐│
││              Total Time: 0.0560s             ││
│└──────────────────────────────────────────────┘│
└────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
┌───────────────────────────┐
│           QUERY           │
└─────────────┬─────────────┘
┌─────────────┴─────────────┐
│      EXPLAIN_ANALYZE      │
│    ────────────────────   │
│           0 Rows          │
│          (0.00s)          │
└─────────────┬─────────────┘
┌─────────────┴─────────────┐
│      CREATE_TABLE_AS      │
│    ────────────────────   │
│           1 Rows          │
│          (0.01s)          │
└─────────────┬─────────────┘
┌─────────────┴─────────────┐
│         PROJECTION        │
│    ────────────────────   │
│           asset           │
│            year           │
│         rep_period        │
│      time_block_start     │
│          indices          │
│         durations         │
│                           │
│        220460 Rows        │
│          (0.00s)          │
└─────────────┬─────────────┘
┌─────────────┴─────────────┐
│         HASH_JOIN         │
│    ────────────────────   │
│      Join Type: LEFT      │
│                           │
│        Conditions:        │
│       asset = asset       │
│        year = year        ├──────────────┐
│  rep_period = rep_period  │              │
│     time_block_start =    │              │
│      time_block_start     │              │
│                           │              │
│        220460 Rows        │              │
│          (0.04s)          │              │
└─────────────┬─────────────┘              │
┌─────────────┴─────────────┐┌─────────────┴─────────────┐
│         TABLE_SCAN        ││         PROJECTION        │
│    ────────────────────   ││    ────────────────────   │
│           t_cons          ││__internal_decompress_strin│
│                           ││           g(#0)           │
│        Projections:       ││__internal_decompress_integ│
│           asset           ││    ral_bigint(#1, 2030)   │
│            year           ││__internal_decompress_integ│
│         rep_period        ││     ral_bigint(#2, 1)     │
│      time_block_start     ││__internal_decompress_integ│
│                           ││     ral_bigint(#3, 1)     │
│                           ││             #4            │
│                           ││             #5            │
│                           ││                           │
│        220460 Rows        ││        220460 Rows        │
│          (0.00s)          ││          (0.00s)          │
└───────────────────────────┘└─────────────┬─────────────┘
                             ┌─────────────┴─────────────┐
                             │       HASH_GROUP_BY       │
                             │    ────────────────────   │
                             │          Groups:          │
                             │             #0            │
                             │             #1            │
                             │             #2            │
                             │             #3            │
                             │                           │
                             │        Aggregates:        │
                             │       array_agg(#4)       │
                             │       array_agg(#5)       │
                             │                           │
                             │        220460 Rows        │
                             │          (0.15s)          │
                             └─────────────┬─────────────┘
                             ┌─────────────┴─────────────┐
                             │         PROJECTION        │
                             │    ────────────────────   │
                             │          to_asset         │
                             │            year           │
                             │         rep_period        │
                             │      time_block_start     │
                             │       variable_index      │
                             │          duration         │
                             │                           │
                             │        1372400 Rows       │
                             │          (0.00s)          │
                             └─────────────┬─────────────┘
                             ┌─────────────┴─────────────┐
                             │         PROJECTION        │
                             │    ────────────────────   │
                             │__internal_compress_string_│
                             │        hugeint(#0)        │
                             │__internal_compress_integra│
                             │    l_utinyint(#1, 2030)   │
                             │__internal_compress_integra│
                             │     l_utinyint(#2, 1)     │
                             │__internal_compress_integra│
                             │     l_usmallint(#3, 1)    │
                             │             #4            │
                             │             #5            │
                             │                           │
                             │        1372400 Rows       │
                             │          (0.01s)          │
                             └─────────────┬─────────────┘
                             ┌─────────────┴─────────────┐
                             │         TABLE_SCAN        │
                             │    ────────────────────   │
                             │     t_incoming_nonzero    │
                             │                           │
                             │        Projections:       │
                             │          to_asset         │
                             │            year           │
                             │         rep_period        │
                             │      time_block_start     │
                             │       variable_index      │
                             │          duration         │
                             │                           │
                             │        1372400 Rows       │
                             │          (0.01s)          │
                             └───────────────────────────┘


Example input and expected output:
CREATE
OR REPLACE TABLE t_flows (
    from_asset text,
    to_asset text,
    YEAR int,
    rep_period int,
    time_block_start int,
    time_block_end int,
    variable_index int
);

--
INSERT INTO
    t_flows
VALUES
    ('producer1', 'hub', 2030, 1, 1, 3, 1),
    ('producer1', 'hub', 2030, 1, 4, 6, 2),
    ('producer1', 'hub', 2030, 1, 7, 9, 3),
    ('producer1', 'hub', 2030, 1, 10, 12, 4),
    ('hub', 'demand', 2030, 1, 1, 4, 5),
    ('hub', 'demand', 2030, 1, 5, 8, 6),
    ('hub', 'demand', 2030, 1, 9, 12, 7);

--
CREATE
OR REPLACE TABLE t_cons (
    asset text,
    YEAR int,
    rep_period int,
    time_block_start int,
    time_block_end int
);

--
INSERT INTO
    t_cons
VALUES
    ('hub', 2030, 1, 1, 5),
    ('hub', 2030, 1, 6, 6),
    ('hub', 2030, 1, 7, 8),
    ('hub', 2030, 1, 9, 12);

┌─────────┬───────┬────────────┬──────────────────┬─────────┬───────────┐
│  asset  │ YEAR  │ rep_period │ time_block_start │ indices │ durations │
│ varchar │ int32 │   int32    │      int32       │ int32[] │  int32[]  │
├─────────┼───────┼────────────┼──────────────────┼─────────┼───────────┤
│ hub     │  2030 │          1 │                1 │ [1, 2]  │ [3, 2]    │
│ hub     │  2030 │          1 │                6 │ [2]     │ [1]       │
│ hub     │  2030 │          1 │                7 │ [3]     │ [2]       │
│ hub     │  2030 │          1 │                9 │ [3, 4]  │ [1, 3]    │
└─────────┴───────┴────────────┴──────────────────┴─────────┴───────────┘


To help us understand what you're trying to do, please show sample data and expected output, ideally with a link to an SQL fiddle.

Have you created any indexes on the tables? If not, then consider adding indexes on columns or groups of columns used as criteria in JOIN and WHERE clauses. Run EXPLAIN(ANALYZE,BUFFERS,SETTINGS,VERBOSE) and add the results as inline text to the orignial post. Examining the explain plan will help identify the most expensive parts of processing the query.

Thank you both, I've added an example and the output of EXPLAIN. DuckDB only supports EXPLAIN ANALYZE, though. I'll look into creating index now

I suggest considering a more compact query.
Temporary tables are not created.
If you need assets and periods for which there is no data, try replacing INNER JOIN with LEFT JOIN.
You should create indexes to improve performance. Perhaps index on t_cons(asset, YEAR, rep_period, time_block_start) and on t_flow(to_asset,year,rep_period).
SELECT
    asset,
    year,
    rep_period,
    time_block_start,
    array_agg(variable_index) AS indices,
    array_agg(duration) AS durations
FROM(
  SELECT
    t_cons.asset,
    t_flows.from_asset,
    t_flows.to_asset,
    t_flows.year,
    t_flows.rep_period,
    t_flows.variable_index,
    t_cons.time_block_start,
    greatest(
        0,
        1 + least(t_flows.time_block_end, t_cons.time_block_end) - greatest(t_flows.time_block_start, t_cons.time_block_start)
      ) AS duration
  FROM t_flows
  INNER JOIN t_cons ON t_flows.to_asset = t_cons.asset
    AND t_flows.year = t_cons.year
    AND t_flows.rep_period = t_cons.rep_period
 )t
WHERE  duration > 0
GROUP BY asset, YEAR, rep_period, time_block_start

Fiddle (postgresql)
Update1.
try use condition
least(t_flows.time_block_end, t_cons.time_block_end) - greatest(t_flows.time_block_start, t_cons.time_block_start)

in on clause.
This should significantly reduce the JOIN result.
SELECT
    asset,
    year,
    rep_period,
    time_block_start,
    array_agg(variable_index) AS indices,
    array_agg(duration) AS durations
FROM(
  SELECT
    t_cons.asset,
    t_flows.from_asset,
    t_flows.to_asset,
    t_flows.year,
    t_flows.rep_period,
    t_flows.variable_index,
    t_cons.time_block_start,
    greatest(
        0,
        1 + least(t_flows.time_block_end, t_cons.time_block_end) - greatest(t_flows.time_block_start, t_cons.time_block_start)
      ) AS duration
  FROM t_flows
  INNER JOIN t_cons ON t_flows.to_asset = t_cons.asset
    AND t_flows.year = t_cons.year
    AND t_flows.rep_period = t_cons.rep_period
    AND least(t_flows.time_block_end, t_cons.time_block_end) >= greatest(t_flows.time_block_start, t_cons.time_block_start)
 )t
WHERE  duration > 0
GROUP BY asset, YEAR, rep_period, time_block_start
;

Perhaps, clause WHERE  duration > 0 in this  case may be removed.
Fiddle

Sorry for the delay, thanks for the answer. Unfortunately it doesn't improve the query yet. The inner join is still performed for the whole query according to the EXPLAIN output
